# DateTime in Snowflake Timestamp '23-Jan-2015 23:02:39' is not recognized

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a varchar that I am converting to a DateTime and I'm using the below syntax but I get the following error in Snowflake "Timestamp '23-Jan-2015 23:02:39' is not recognized". Since I'll be getting my data in this format what do you suggest?

`select '23-Jan-2015 23:02:39'::timestamp_tz;`

Answer (score 2):

Your timestamp string literal is not in a standard format which Postgres can directly use.  Instead, you may use `TO_TIMESTAMP` to convert:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('23-Jan-2015 23:02:39', 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

In the demo tool I used, this returned: `2015-01-23 23:02:39+00`

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You need to let snowflake know how to make sense of the literal that you are passing.

1. Use the to_timestamp() to instruct it to convert to a timestamp
2. Give it a way to map the day-month-year while it parses the literal to map it to values

`select to_timestamp('23-Jan-2015 23:02:39', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');`

Please check the supported  Date ,Time , Timestamp etc formats supported by Snowflake here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#date-formats